# Python Dash DataTable with multiply tbodies

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I need to add multiply tbody’es or some sort of id’s to the selected rows in dynamically updated dash DataTable so I can hide them using CSS in the future.
Is there any way to do so?
jQuery is not an option, because it doesn't work so well on load with dynamic pages. So css hide() is an only option, but I can't find needed row by row text as with jQuery.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: share your code to get more help

Answer (score 0):

```
import dash, random, datetime
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Title, db_connect, create_table, Domain

columns= [column.key for column in Title.__table__.columns]

external_stylesheets = ['https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css']

engine = db_connect()
create_table(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.scripts.append_script({"external_url": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"})

app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable',
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in columns],
        data=[],),
    dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=1*5000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
    ),
],)


@app.callback(Output('datatable', 'data'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),])
def update_metrics(n):
    query = session.query(Title).all()
    data = []
    for q in query:
        title = q.__dict__
        del title['_sa_instance_state']
        data.append(title)
    return data
```

Comment: this code generates just a simple table with <tr> and <td>. I need to add <tbody> somehow or id.